# Replace specific character of item in list - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a very simple guitar tab creator in python, I had the idea but i'm not sure how to execute it the way I want. For example, I have a list containing each guitar string as a different item in the list, and I want the the user to be able to input which fret they want to use and which note. How can I replace a specific char in a list item based on a index number.

This is what I have so far:

```
tab = ['E|------------', 'B|------------', 'G|------------', 'D|------------', 'A|------------', 'E|------------']

for line in tab:
    print(line)

fret = input("Fret: ")
note = input("Note: ")

#if note == 'E':
   (Stuck here)
```

The output I'm looking for is something like:

```
e|-------5-7-----7-|-8-----8-2-----2-|-0---------0-----|-----------------|
B|-----5-----5-----|---5-------3-----|---1---1-----1---|-0-1-1-----------|
G|---5---------5---|-----5-------2---|-----2---------2-|-0-2-2---2-------|
D|-7-------6-------|-5-------4-------|-3---------------|-----------------|
A|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-2-0-0---0--/8-7-|
E|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
```

I am aware that there is much more needed to get the output i'm looking for, but I want to try to figure that stuff out by myself first, I'm just looking for a nudge in the right direction to get a list item changed.

Comment: Python `string`s don't support item assignment through indexing, so it might be inconvenient to have each string as an actual string instead of a list of characters. You could convert them to lists and use indexing to replace a character through assignment, so directly from your example: 
`tmp = list(tab[0])[fret]=note`, convert it back to a string with `new_string = "".join(tmp)`

Comment: What about building a fret, like `fret = "D|"+("-"*1)+"7"+("-"*7)+"6"+("-"*7)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note sure how you want to construct the whole thing, but here are some ideas:

The main line is

```py
"-".join(str(d.get(idx, "-")) for idx in range(1, 9))
```

which, given a dict `d` having indices as keys and corresponding fret numbers as values, construct the string representation.

It uses the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20get#dict.get) method which allows for a default value of `"-"` when nothing corresponds in the given dict.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

def construct_string(indices, frets):
    d = dict(zip(indices, frets))
    out = "-".join(str(d.get(idx, "-")) for idx in range(1, 9))
    return f"-{out}-"

String = namedtuple("Note", ["indices", "frets"])

strings = {
    "e": String([4, 5, 8], [5, 7, 7]),
    "B": String([3, 6], [5, 5]),
    "G": String([2, 7], [5, 5]),
    "D": String([1, 5], [7, 6]),
    "A": String([], []),
    "E": String([], []),
}

for string_name, string in strings.items():
    string_line = construct_string(string.indices, string.frets)
    print(f"{string_name}|{string_line}")
```

which prints:

```
e|-------5-7-----7-
B|-----5-----5-----
G|---5---------5---
D|-7-------6-------
A|-----------------
E|-----------------
```

Comment: This is good. I'd suggest `Note` should be plural, `Notes`, and `notes` dict should be `strings`.  Also I'm guessing the OP did not have 17 divisions per bar, but 8 with `-` spacers and end-caps. But this gets the important idea across of having a data structure for the grid and then build the printable output from that.

Comment: @Anentropic yes I don't know anything about guitar so I was expecting making some semantic mistakes. As you said the usage of a suitable data structure is the main point here.

Comment: @Anentropic is it more correct now?